# Image in Splash Screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, screen, splash-screen

Good afternoon, I'm trying to change the image of my app that appears on the Splash Screen of my app but it is not being changed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RtNt.png)

As you can see I made all the changes and here are my folders

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vhjp.png)